# how to go to next line if match is found and again check for the word count in that line

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to find word count by find a match line if match is found go to next line and count the word in that line

```
id = open('id.txt','r')
ids = id.readlines()
for i in range(0, len(ids) - 1, 1):
    actual_id = ids[i]
    print(actual_id)
    with open('sample2.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.search(r'{actual_id}|RQ', line):
                next_line = line.next()
                if next_line == 'RQ':

                print(line)
                with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
                    f.write('\n' + line)
```

**Sample.txt** text file:

```
[07-12-2022 13:27:45.728|Info|0189B31C|RQ]
<ServiceRQ><SaleInfo><CityCode Solution=1>BLQ</CityCode><CountryCode Solution=2>NL</CountryCode><CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode><Channel>ICI</Channel></ServiceRQ>

[07-12-2022 13:27:45.744|Info|0189B31D|RQ]
<ServiceRQ><SaleInfo><CityCode Solution=1>BLQ</CityCode><CountryCode>NL</CountryCode><CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode><Channel>ICI</Channel></ServiceRQ>
```

**0189B31C**

**0189B31D**

These are unique id's which are store in different text file I am trying to read the 1st id from text file and match that id in Sample.txt and if match is found go to next line and count the number of **Solution** words and print.
Please can someone help me for find the code I am little confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the "requests" module. But since no one has answered your question yet, I thought maybe this would suit you. The code should work fine if the number of lines is even.  I mean, the code will put strings in the "payload" and do the rest only if there is an entire pair consisting of an odd and an even string.

```
with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            odd_line=next(f)
            even_line=next(f)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        #payload=...
        #headers=...
        #response=...
        #print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flag [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) with the regex `{idf}\|RQ.*?</ServiceRQ>`, this way the regex matches any character including a newline, and the non-greedy modifier (`.*?`) part makes sure that few characters as possible will be matched until the string `</ServiceRQ>` is found. Then, you can use `findall` to obtain the number of `Solution` words in the string.

```py
import re

with open('sample2.txt', 'r') as sample_file:
    sample2 = sample_file.read()

id_dict = {}
with open('id.txt', 'r') as id_file:
    for idf in id_file.read().split():
        id_found = re.findall(fr'{idf}\|RQ.*?</ServiceRQ>', sample2, re.DOTALL)
        if id_found:
            solution_found = re.findall('Solution', id_found[0])
            id_dict[idf] = len(solution_found)

print(id_dict)
```

Output from *id_dict*

```py
{
    '0189B31C': 2,
    '0189B31D': 1
}
```